# Deleting elemnt from array and calculating sum

Tags: c++

Number can't be in array if it can be divided by number of elements of array (for example: in array which has 10 elements, numbers 1,2,5 and 10 are not "welcome"). So I need to find all these elements in array and kick them out. After that length of array changes, and then some other elements can be "not welcome" in array. I have to repeat it until array is without these elements. In the end, I have to calculate remaining elements and print them out. (I'm using C++)

- I didn't know how to delete element from array, and just set value to 0.
  I get input n (number of elements in array) and then all of these elements.

So, I already tried it but I'm sure there is much more effective way to do it :P Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    short int b = 0;
    short int n;
    int result = 0;
    cin >> n;
    int m = n;
    int numbers[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j<=n; j++) {
       if(numbers[j] != 0) {
        if(n % numbers[j] == 0) {
            numbers[j] = 0;
            b = b + 1;
        } }
    }
    n = n - b;
    b = 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    result += numbers[i];
}

cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```

example input: 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
example output: 24

Comment: Is this a classroom assignment that requires using an array? If not then using a `std::vector` would be a much better choice.

Comment: C++ doesn't really have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). A couple of compilers add it as a non-portable extension to the language, but you really shouldn't use them.

Comment: Yeah, it is for school. Can it be done without removing elements? Somehow with using arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't know how to delete element from array

It is not possible to "delete element from array". An array of `n` elements begins its life with `n` elements, has `n` elements throughout its entire lifetime, and ends its life with `n` elements. It is not possible  to change the size of an array.

---

Another problem:

> ```
> cin >> n;
> int numbers[n];
> ```

The size of an array must be a compile time constant. `n` is not a compile time constant. This is not a well-formed C++ program.

An array of runtime size must be allocated dynamically. The easiest solution is to use `std::vector`. The size of a vector can change, and you can use `std::vector::erase` to remove elements from it.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way of doing this with arrays?

Comment: @LukaMitrovic There is no way of removing elements from an array. You can set elements to zero, like in your solution.